# What should be taken into consideration when designing a logo for a construction news portal

Tags: logo, design-principles

I'm new to designing.
I'm learning graphic designing and for practice I've taken up a project.
I've to design a logo for a construction news portal called 'constructmate'
they said they want at least two of following colours: yellow, orange, green, purple and with bold fonts. and it should have something that says that the company is still emerging or flourishing.

Till now what i've managed to do is this:

[image]

[image]

they like what i've done with abbreviation, but with full name it doesn't have the required imapct, that's what they said. Please guide me. I've to include the full name, what should i do?

Thanks for all help.